# Scrapy will extract in shell but no output when running code

Tags: python, web-scraping, scapy

I am able to scrape in Shell, but in the actual spider I am getting an empty dictionary. I am using the same selectors in shell and in the program.

```
import scrapy 

class Earls(scrapy.Spider): 
    name = 'earls_spider'   
    start_urls = [
        'https://earls.ca/locations/dalhousie/menu/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_earls_happy_hour = response.css('#happy-hour .pt5')

        for section in all_earls_happy_hour:
            earls_food_item = section.css("#happy-hour .sub-section+ .sub-section .tl::text").extract()
            earls_food_price = section.css("#happy-hour .sub-section+ .sub-section .actual::text").extract()
            earls_drink_items = section.css("#happy-hour .sub-section+ .sub-section .tl::text").extract()
            earls_drink_price = section.css("#happy-hour .items-center+ .sub-section .actual::text").extract()
            yield {
                'earls_HH_food': earls_food_item,
                'earls_food_price': earls_food_price,
                'earls_drink_items': earls_drink_items,
                'earls_drink_price': earls_drink_price
            }
```

When I run this code the output is an empty dict:
{'earls_HH_food': [], 'earls_food_price': [], 'earls_drink_items': [], 'earls_drink_price': []}

However I am able to run response.css() in shell with the same selectors above and it is able to scrape and return the desired output. What am I missing in the actual program???

Comment: Can you show us the equivalent shell code that works

Comment: >>> response.css("#happy-hour .sub-section+ .sub-section .tl::text").extract()
['Crispy Prawn Sushi Taco', 'Spicy Tuna Sushi Taco', 'Crispy Tofu Sushi Taco', 'Fries or Truffle Fries', 'Street Chicken Tacos', 'Yam Fries', '3 Crispy Tofu Sushi Tacos', 'Street Corn + Avocado Dip', '3 Crispy Prawn Sushi Tacos', 'Margherita Pizza', '3 Spicy Tuna Sushi Tacos', 'Half Dozen Oysters On The Half Shell', 'Prawn Cocktail', 'Ahi Tuna Poke Bowl', 'Jumbo Lump Crab Cake', 'Earls Chicken Biryani', '6 oz Steak Frites', 'Seafood Platter']

Comment: I'm not a crawler expert, but those two codes seem different to me.  The crawler code does `response.css('#happy-hour .pt5')` and then does a further `section.css("#happy-hour .sub-section+ .sub-section .tl::text").extract()` on each result from the first query, but the shell code jumps straight to the second query.

Comment: I would presume that `#happy-hour .pt5` is consumed by the first query, and thus the `#happy-hour` element is not present in the section subquery, thus it finds no matches.

Comment: I tried removing the #happy-hour .pt5 in the selector after the for loop but still returning an empty dict. Not sure how to get around this. Technically using the selector #happy-hour .pt5 and assigning it to all_earls_happy_hour is supposed to allow me to select different items in the "#hapy-hour .pt5" section.

Comment: I haven't worked with Scrapy so I don't know for certain, but I would expect that the results from the first `response.css` are hierarchical, so the initial `#happy-hour` element is not present in the section sub-querys.

Comment: Unless there really is another `#happy-hour` element nested underneath the first one.